# How to aggregate the dataframe into one using python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

DF1:

```
Product         Party   x   y   Currency    Parent  Child
Purchase    5AAA64870   2   0.1 USD         Apple   Smartphone
Purchase    5AAA64870   1   0.3 USD         Apple   Smartphone
Purchase    5AAA64870   1   0.3 USD         Apple   Smartphone
Purchase    5AAA64870   1   0.3 USD         Apple   Smartphone
Purchase    5AAA64870   1   0.3 USD         Apple   Smartphone
Purchase    5AAA64870   1   0.3 USD         Apple   Smartphone
```

Expected output:

```
Product     Party       x   y   Currency    Parent  Child
Purchase    5AAA64870   7   1.6 USD         Apple   Smartphone
```

Code:

```
df1 = df1[df1['Product'] == 'Purchase'].groupby(
            ['Product', 'Party'])['x', 'y'].sum()
```

Sorry, this sounds very easy question, but I am unable to aggregate the data into one row like the above expected output. Appreciate your help in this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was pretty easy :). But just because you are a newbee i am gonna explain the logic behind it, so when you groupby and pass a list. Pandas basically says okay this is now the index so if the index is equal another index i shall smush them together. If you add index columns, well he is gonna smush them together according to your elements.

```
df1[df1['Product'] == 'Purchase'].groupby(
                ['Product', 'Party','Parent','Currency','Child'],as_index=False)['x', 'y'].sum()
```

Comment: Thanks for the awesome explanation and the code, appreciate it!